# EditText Crashes App When It Set to Empty ( Android )

Tags: java, android

I have an EditText and when I set it to Empty and Click on my Button, my App crashes.

When I view it in Android Monitor it points to the line:

```
final int addTm = Integer.parseInt(Teaching);
```

Here is my code:

LinearLayout

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tM"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:ems="1"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:text="0" />
           <Button
            android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

And my Java Code:

```
Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String Teaching = Tm.getText().toString();
            final int addTm = Integer.parseInt(Teaching);

            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("sub").child("TM");
            myRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                @Override
                public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                    Integer currentValue = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                    if (currentValue == null) {
                        mutableData.setValue(0);
                    } else {
                        mutableData.setValue(currentValue + addTm);
                    }

                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    System.out.println("Transaction completed");
                }

            });
         }
    });
```

Comment: It's not a `firebase`  issue, so kindly remove this tag, and you are getting this error because by default the `EditText` returns an empty string which can not be `parsed`  to an `integer`. Perform some exception handling and you are good to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are good, but I'd recommend wrapping with a try/catch for the `NumberFormatException`. I know you have the input set to accept numbers only, but always better safe than sorry.

Lowercase the String variable Teaching. In Java we only upper case Type names. (classes, interfaces, etc.) Notice how StackOverflow is highlighting the variable Teaching blue, a bit disorienting no?

Do this for your member fields as well Tm and Submit. They should be written tm and submit. Also, Tm is not a very descriptive name for a variable either. Imagine another programmer coming in and looking at your code, and wondering what a tm is. What is the context of this tm, where does it come from... what does it do? Is it a Teenage Mutant?

Regardless when using `Integer.parseInt` wrap it in a try/catch:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){

        final int addTm;
        try {
            String teaching = Tm.getText().toString();
            addTm = Integer.parseInt(teaching);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            addTm = 0;
        }

        // ...
    }
```

Why should you do this? What if I enter a decimal number into your number input?

Using your accepted answer you will still crash. `Integer.parseInt` does not parse decimal numbers.

Or how about, if I switch the locale of the device and enter a number with odd characters that `Integer.parseInt` won't expect.

Gotta catch that exception to be full proof.

Comment: Thanks for Giving me So much Knowledge about that . I'm A beginner At Android Level. And Tm Is Teaching Methodology !

Answer (score 0):

When executing `Integer.parseInt()` on an empty string it [throws an `NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).

First, check the value of `Teaching`, and verify it's not empty string, or - try/catch for `NumberFormatException`, and set the value you want for `Teaching` in that case.